# Ember View not displaying?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
//The HTML
<div class="content">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <h1>Application</h1>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user-list">
      <h2>Users</h2>
      <ul>
      {{#each App.userController}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </script>
</div>

//The JS
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});

App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    xs:0,
    turnover:0,
    surveys:0
});

App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'user-list'
});

App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/', function(data) {

            me.set('content', []);

            $(data).each(function(index, value) {
                var t = App.User.create({
                    name: value.name,
                    xs: value.xs,
                    turnover: value.turnover,
                    surveys: value.surveys
                });

                me.pushObject(t);
            });
        });
    }
});

App.router = Ember.Router.create({
    enableLogging: true,

    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route:'/',
            connectOutlets:function(router) {
                return router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
                    viewClass: App.UsersView,
                    controller: App.userController
                });
            }
        }),
    })
});

App.initialize(App.router);
```

`userController` *is* fetching the data correctly. I think the issue is with the view. `<h2>Users</h2>` isn't even displayed on the page (Although Application is)

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to include that: `v1.0.0-pre.4`

Comment: I guess you have migrated this code from an old version of Ember and now it stops working? This is because you are using the old Router API there. The new router API does not work that way anymore...

Comment: It was an example I got off the internet. Cheers for that! I will have to look for a newer one

Comment: Have a look at this guide: http://twbrandt.github.com/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide/

Comment: IMHO this is very good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The version differences between Ember versions have been tough to follow over the past few months. I usually discount code which was posted prior to January unless I know it wasn't impacted by the breaking changes.

Here's an example for RC1, working as of 3/12/2013:
http://jsfiddle.net/nrionfx/Se2Bw/1/

(It's in Coffeescript - I primarily write Ruby and find it much more readable...)

```
App.UsersController = Em.ArrayController.extend
    title: 'users controller'
    content: []

App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend
    enter: ->
        console?.log('users route')
    setupController: (controller) ->
        #Do your AJAX call here and set the content array upon success
        ct= [
            App.User.create({id: 1, name: 'Bill', xs:0}),
            App.User.create({id: 2, name: 'Bob', xs:0}),
        ]
        controller.set('content', ct)
        #END AJAX

App.Router.map (match) ->
    @route "users", path: "/"
```